# 'Contract' object has no attribute 'eventFilter' web3.py

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, events, filters, web3.py

I am trying to filter Transfer events from my local ethereum node using web3 py. I have created a venv in visual studio code. My code is as follows:

```
def decodeLogswithfilter(t1, t2, abi1, addr):
    mycontract = geth.eth.contract(address=addr, abi=abi1)
    filter = mycontract.eventFilter(
        'Transfer', {'fromBlock': t1, 'toBlock': t2})
    eventlist = filter.get_all_entries
    print(eventlist)

decodeLogswithfilter(start, ending_block,
                         abi['result'], geth.toChecksumAddress(current_addr))
```

I have also tried using createFilter as well but it gives me the same error that Contract object has no attribute eventFilter.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/ssd/erc721/queryBlockchain.py", line 150, in <module>
    abi['result'], geth.toChecksumAddress(current_addr))
  File "/mnt/ssd/erc721/queryBlockchain.py", line 71, in decodeLogswithfilter
    filter = mycontract.eventFilter(
AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'eventFilter'
```

I have also tried upgrading my web3 package as suggested online, but the error didn't resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
filter = mycontract.eventFilter(
        'Transfer', {'fromBlock': t1, 'toBlock': t2})
eventlist = filter.get_all_entries
```

with

```
filter = mycontract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock=t1, toBlock=t2 )
filter.get_all_entries()
```

assuming Transfer is the eventname in solidity, This is for web3==5.5.1 version.

Comment: I did and got the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ethereumpc1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/providers/ipc.py", line 239, in make_request
    raw_response += sock.recv(4096)
socket.timeout: timed out

Comment: Make sure your local eth blockchain is working, This error implies that connection couldn't be established.

Comment: The local blockchain is working, but the code is still throwing the same error.

Comment: It seems everytime i run the code the node gets disconnected and the system  hangs.  Im using the system remotely through teamviewer. Is it because of a poor internet connection?

Comment: Are u talking about remix?

Comment: You can deploy it on local ganache, you can also deploy it on Testnet and connect your web3.py with infra .

Comment: check this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/82386/37596